# Sci-fi film: Underground self-healing machine that fires rocks out of a tunnel

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the late eighties/early nineties I watched a film on the television.  The only scene I remember clearly was when the hero is on a desert like planet.  Massive great big spherical rocks were flying into a tunnel in which a machine remelted them and reformed them back into spheres.  They were then fired back out of the tunnel.  I don't know why.

Then the next bit I remember was that the man went down the tunnel (it was very dangerous to do so) and climbed onto the gantry and took a hammer to the controlling computer and tried to destroy it.  But every piece he smashed off floated out a little way but then floated back into place.  The machine was indestructible and self-repairing/healing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You can improve this question by checking the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for writing a good story-id question.  For example, do you remember what channel it was on, or what language it was in?

Comment: I saw it on TV in the UK, so it would have been the BBC, Channel 4 or ITV.  No idea what language it was in, I don't recall any speech.  The above is all I can remember about it!  I'd love to see it again though.

Comment: was it live action or animated?

Comment: It was live action.